"The lesson will begin soon" vs "The lesson begins soon"
To talk about a fixed schedule in the future, we often use the present simple. For example:


The lesson begins at 9 p.m. tonight.


However, when the time is not specified but it's still a fixed schedule, the present simple suddenly sounds off to me:


The lesson begins soon.


In this case, the future simple sounds better:


Hurry up! The lesson will begin soon.


Instinctively, I'll choose the future simple here; however, when I think about it, I don't know which use of the tense this sentence falls into because the future simple often implies a decision made at the time speaking, a prediction, a request or a promise.
Besides, can I say the below sentence because it doesn't seem to fall into any uses either.


The lesson will begin at 9 p.m. tonight.


Note that in all of the above examples, with or without mentioning the time, the lesson's schedule is still fixed, so the fact that it'll happen soon is not a prediction.
P.S. I've found a use that might explain why (3) sounds good, but this use only appears in one source so I'm not sure if it's legit. In addition, this doesn't explain why (2) sounds off if it's actually the case.

The Future Simple represents events or actions that are about to happen in the near future


When you first learn tenses in English, it's helpful to have particular rules: use this tense in this case, that tense in that different case. This is understandable. But my advice is to try and get to the level where you stop asking, Which tense is right? Instead you want to ask, What does this tense mean?
This is a big but important change of focus. It's important because often different tenses can both be right, but they will mean different things. Take for example the first sentence in the OP. Both of these versions are correct, but they have a slightly different focus:


The lesson begins at 9 p.m. tonight. (The present tense focuses on this present moment: As we speak, there exists a lesson scheduled to begin at 9pm.)
The lesson will begin at 9 p.m. tonight. (The future tense now focuses on the start time: Remember tonight's lesson? It will begin at 9pm.)


The problem with focussing on the rules and not the meaning can be seen clearly when the OP has a problem with the sentence The lesson will begin soon. The problem arises because:

I don't know which use of the tense this sentence falls into because the future simple often implies a decision made at the time speaking, a prediction, a request or a promise.

My response to that is simple. Those are rules. There's nothing wrong with the rules. Those are indeed a list of cases when the future tense is used in English.  But if we thought about meaning, we might have asked ourselves, I want to talk about something in the future; what tense is the best for that? Answer: The future tense!
Note that here too there are choices. You can say the meeting begins soon or the meeting will begin soon, and they have the same set of differences as explained earlier.

Thank you. I see your point: Most of the time, we can say a sentence using different tenses; they just mean different things. But in the end, when the context and the intended meaning have been specified, which tense is best to use still boils down to whether it is used by native speakers to deliver that meaning, or in other words but in a more technical way, whether it has that use. For example, you have just given me a new use of the future simple (will), which is to talk about a fixed schedule when we want to emphasize the start time...

...To not be faced with this problem again, perhaps I'll have to learn more uses than just the common ones generally taught by English teachers. So, your advice is great in theory, but it seemingly doesn't change how I'll have to learn tenses in the future.

I don't want my advice to be "just theoretical." My practical response is to treat this as a parallel learning experience. Learning new rules is fine. But at the same time ask yourself the question: What does this mean? And how would it change the meaning if I changed the tense? Then you are learning how tenses are used to express a range of meanings.

For example, did you ask why the present tense is used in your sentence 1? After all, the event is still in the future. What is "present" about it? Answer: The scheduling of the event, not the event itself.
